# Computing the infinite sum, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {5^n}{25^n + 1} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

So I'm trying to compute $$ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {5^n}{25^n + 1}. $$ The [closed form](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+m+%3D+0+to+k+of+5%5Em%2F%2825%5Em+%2B+1%29) is not very nice and I don't see any immediate telescoping. Any ideas?

Comment: It is merely partial fractions (that is if you accept $\psi^{0}$ as a closed form !)

Comment: @sciona Partial fractions; really? How? I don't see how you can decompose $ \frac {x}{x^2 + 1} $ further.

Comment: Presumably the closed form at your link is as simple as possible, so are you asking for a way to compute the sum numerically? The terms go to zero quickly, so just doing the addition of the first few terms should give a good answer.

Comment: The doubly-infinite series $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac {5^n}{25^n + 1}.$$ can be written in terms of Jacobi theta functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since:
$$\frac{5^n}{25^n+1}=\frac{1}{5^n}-\frac{1}{125^n}+\frac{1}{3125^n}-\ldots $$
we have:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{5^n}{25^n+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{124}+\frac{1}{3124}+\ldots\right)=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{5^{2k+1}-1}.$$

---

Despite being easy to compute through Euler's acceleration technique, such a series does not have a nice closed expression. Otherwise, also the [reciprocal Lucas constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalLucasConstant.html) would have one.

Comment: Thanks, but how is the final sum of $ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^k}{5^{2k+1}-1} $ easier to calculate than the original one?

Comment: @AhaanRungta: its terms go faster to zero and it is an alternating series, so by summing the first $k$ terms the error is less than the absolute value of the $k$-th term.

Comment: Many thanks for the response, but my point was to try to find the exact answer with proof, as the "approximate with a few terms method" could be applied quite easily.

Comment: @AhaanRungta: Wolfram Alpha already gave you the exact answer.

Comment: <quote>
exact answer with proof
</quote>

Comment: @AhaanRungta: The just have a look at the definition of the $\psi_5$ function - Wolfram alpha does not state  something much different from stating *this series equal this series*.

Answer (score 2):

**hint:**

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {5^n}{25^n + 1} = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {1}{5^n + 5^{-n}}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {1}{e^{\ln(5)n} + e^{-\ln(5)n}}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {1}{2\cosh(\ln(5)n)} $$

if you could find a formula for $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {1}{\cosh(xn)} $$
you have soved the problem. and ***maybe*** it can be computed by residue theory in complex function.

Comment: Love this way of approaching it; one question though, why have you chosen to write $2 \cosh(-\ln(5)n)$ instead of noting that $\cosh$ is even? Is it something to do with the fact that the argument is a $\ln$?

Comment: @Autolatry: you are right , I corrected.

Comment: Many thanks, that's great!

Answer (score 1):

Your series is a [Lambert series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html) and in the case of constant coefficients $a_n$ it may be rewritten as a [classical Jacobi theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) (for $z=0$) : $$\theta_3(z,q):=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2\pi iz}$$
using the relation $(8)$ from the initial MathWorld link with $\;q=\dfrac 15$ :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {q^n}{1+q^{2n}}=\frac{\theta_3(0,q)^2-1}4$$
This is in fact an identity from Jacobi (a proof is given in chap.$9$ of Borwein&Borwein's excellent book "Pi and the AGM").

It may be written too as an elliptic function as provided in relation $(2.7)$ of this paper from Stephen Milne ["Infinite families of exact sums of squares formulas, Jacobi elliptic functions, continued fractions, and Schur functions"](http://arXiv.org/abs/math/0008068).

Things may become more complicated instead of more simple but not less interesting !